# Exporting selected object as .blend

Tags: python, scripting, export

I have a blender script that takes each root-level object, duplicates its hierarchy, moves the duplicate to the origin, exports the duplicate as an fbx, and then deletes the duplicate.

I'd like to convert this script to **export .blend instead of .fbx**. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to save selected objects as their own .blend file.

Is there any way to do this, or do I need to make multiple copies of the scene and just delete all of the objects I don't want in each .blend file? If so, is there some best practice so that the artist thinks they're working non-destructively?

Comment: There's an addon that does this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Export_Selected. Another way(which is the way I've done it) is to have a empty .blend that you use to duplicate then add libraries to.

Comment: Thanks @cmomoney. This plugin does use the "delete everything else" method, but it hides it with the undo stack. That may be the direction I need to go.